# ParseInt/text/value from <strong> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've having trouble parsing integers or even text from `<strong>` elements on a page. What I want to do is parse the number of followers from a Twitter profile, like [this one](https://twitter.com/twitterapi). Using Google dev tools, I'm calling:

```
var value = ($('.js-mini-profile-stats strong')[2])
```

Than I'm trying to call  `value.text()` but... oops!

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'text'
```

How do I get text from this element and then parse the integer from it? Unfortunately, the text inside the `<strong>` element has the format `1,353,441`, so calling `parseInt` directly will only get value `1` from it.

Edit: 
Thanks for answers. But stilL I can't parse int from it

```
`value.text();
"=> 1,992,740"
parseInt(value.text());
 => 1`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you apply index to jquery object you get simple html element
so if you want get text in side this element i need use

```
var value = $('.js-mini-profile-stats strong')[2].innerText.replace(/,/g,"")
```

OR

```
var value = $('.js-mini-profile-stats strong')[2].innerHTML.replace(/,/g,"")
```

also you can use jquery

```
var value = $('.js-mini-profile-stats strong:eq(2)').text().replace(/,/g,"")
```

and then parse it like

```
val = parseInt(value, 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you access an element in a jQuery object via index, it returns a raw HTML element and you lose access to all of the jQuery methods. You probably want something like this instead

```
var value = $('.js-mini-profile-stats strong').eq(2);
value.text();
```

Comment: Thank you! But still I have no clue how to parse int from number like that value.text();
"1,992,740"
parseInt(value.text());
1

Comment: @user2160738 just replace space or comma in the string to empty string before parse :-)

Comment: You probably need to strip out any weird characters with a regular expression prior to running it through parseInt - 

     parseInt(value.text().replace(/\,/g, ''));

Comment: @callmehiphop, don't forget radix for `parseInt` :-)

Comment: my bad! - parseInt(value.text().replace(/\,/g, ''), 10);

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the whole thing inside $().

Comment: What does that mean? Whats the "whole thing", and why should that resolve the given problem? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it